# How can this be a vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, vectors

$$\vec{m}' = \langle \Psi' | \vec{\sigma} | \Psi' \rangle
\vec{m} = \langle \Psi | \vec{\sigma} | \Psi \rangle
$$

In the chapter about spin, these two vectors were given, the vector with the ' is supposed to represent an angle rotated by the angle alpha.  The sigma vector is the Pauli matrices.

I thought this notation was always just a number. Unfortunately, the script does not specify exactly how this equation looks written out.

Does anyone know what this equation looks like written out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [vector of Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vector) is $\boldsymbol \sigma = (\sigma_{x}, \sigma_{y}, \sigma_{z})$ and therefore

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol m = \begin{pmatrix}
\langle \psi| \sigma_{x} | \psi \rangle \\
\langle \psi| \sigma_{y} | \psi \rangle \\
\langle \psi| \sigma_{z} | \psi \rangle \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you now I understand it :-)

Comment: If this has answered your question then please consider putting this as the accepted answer :)